# is it possible to wire bond to a perfboard pcb?

Tags: pcb, protoboard, wirebonding

Can a wire bonder bond wires to contacts on a board like this one:
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8808

Comment: Asking an "is it possible" question is usually a bad idea. It is impossible for anyone to **prove** that it is not possible, so the only reasonable answer would be "yes, it is possible". But that doesn't get you any closer to actually solving your problem, does it?

Answer (score 2):

The surface finish should be something like ENIG (Electrolytic Nickel/Immersion Gold) for reliable wire bonding.

[Here](https://www.elekonta.de/en/technologies/surfaces/) are a few other options, none of which is HAL.